# How to prevent calling a function if it's already called?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using joomla 3++.

I'm calling a method from my component's class in my system plugin. Prior to calling this method, I wish to check if it's already been called?

```
public function onAfterInitialise()
{
  MyClass::initialize();
}
```

`if (class_exists('MyClass'))`//always true when navigate among different components

`if (method_exists('MyClass', 'initialize'))`//always true also

`var_dump(MyClass::initialize());`//true

The problem I'm facing:

My system plugin is not running on other components if I don't call this `MyClass::initialize()`.

At the same time, one of the components says a js file is already loaded if I called `MyClass::initialize()` at `onAfterInitialize()`

So I'm thinking probably to avoid a

> xx.js file loaded already issue,

I could check first this `MyClass::initialize()` called or not.

Answer (score 1):

you are calling MyClass::initialize() method right?, in that method use

JFactory::getSession()->set('init_called',1,'your_component');

in system plugin you can check

```
public function onAfterInitialise()
{
  $is_called = JFactory::getSession()->get('init_called','','your_component');
  if($is_called){
    //already called, do any other code
  }else{
    // Not yet called, do any other code
  }
}
```

Now you can check that function already called, make sure session will not clear until logout. any other place clear session use this

```
 JFactory::getSession()->clear('init_called','your_component');
```

Comment: if possible  is there a way not to write anything on initialize() method? But do everything in my plugin itself?

Comment: yaa, its possible, just copy initialize method and paste in plugin , call $this->initialize() . it will work